# ActiveX controll update

Tags: c#, com, activex

I have working web page, that uses ActiveX control
ActiveX control was developed by previous programmer (he is out of reach now)
I did some changes in ActiveX control source code and now I need to somehow change current ActiveX control for my changed.
So my question is

**Q: How to change old ActiveX control for new one on server.**

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: [Managing Versions of a Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768007.aspx)

Comment: Probably it is in a CAB file so you need to build the equivalent CAB. Take a look at what is currently on the server.

Comment: this was very helpfull thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the existing ActiveX is in written in C++ and visual studio, then simply follow the following steps:

1. Make the required changes in the source code.
2. Build the upgraded ActiveX control using the F5 key on the Visual
   Studio.
3. Copy the ActiveX to the server and manually register by writing the
   following code in the cmd with admin rights.  * regsvr32
       "location of your ActiveX control"
4. Now you can use your updated ActiveX control either in IE or any other supported container.